# Through Hive, how to fetch recent record?

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

In hive table (Address table) I have 1000s of records and many records are repeatitive like, 
one record with 10 years back time stamp of my address
one record with 1 year back timestamp on my new address
one record with todays timestamp on my recent address

How can I get the recent address record ?

Comment: `ORDER BY timestamp DESC`?

Answer (score 0):

Use [CTE](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Common+Table+Expression) and [WindowingAndAnalytics](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics) function rank with over and partition by clause you able to do this .

If still feel difficulty share full table schema, and will help in query ..